# ModSecurity Block invalid host referer

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, firewall, mod-security, mod-security2

I need a rule to block all POST requests to wp-login.php,
But I need to check if the referer domain is equal to requested domain name
We need to check such things:

1. check for requested domain value (example: sitename1.com)
2. check for referer domain value (example: sitename1.com)
3. if requested domain is equal to referer domain
4. if request is POST
5. if requested file is wp-login.php

I have the following code to check the referer but I need to check the domain in referer too

```
#Block WP logins with no referring URL
<Locationmatch "/wp-login.php">
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "POST"  "deny,status:401,id:5000130,chain,msg:'wp-login request blocked, no referer'"
SecRule &HTTP_REFERER "@eq 0"
</Locationmatch>
```

in this case I can check the visitor completely and ensure he is a human
appreciate for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but may be this chained rule will help you:

```
SecRule &REQUEST_HEADERS:Referer "!@eq 0" \
    "id:5000130,\
    phase:1,\
    t:none,\
    deny,\
    status:401,\
    chain,\
    msg:'wp-login request blocked, no referer'"
    SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /wp-login.php" \
        "chain"
        SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "@streq POST" \
            "chain"
            SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Host "@rx .*" \
                "capture,\
                chain"
                SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Referer "@streq %{TX.0}"
```

Please keep it mind:

- this chained rule works only if the `Referer` header is set
- the `Host` header must also exists

May be you need an another chained rule, which checks the existence of `Referer` header, if the URI is `/wp-login`, but I think based on the rule above you can produce it.

Comment: Thank you so much, just i think the captured string is host but you are trying to compare referer url

Comment: We need to compare referer domain , not referer url|uri

Comment: Feel free to replace the rule as you want.

Comment: I will try and test then add the final rules, thank you

Comment: You should change the argument of the `@rx` operator to `http(|s):\/\/([^:\/]+)(:(\d)|\/).*`, and the `%{TX.0}` to `%{TX.2}`. In this case, the engine will compare the `Host` header with the host part of `Referer`. I think this is what you need.

Comment: Or may be using `@contains` operator? `SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Referer "@contains %{SERVER_NAME}"` , is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure `%{SERVER_NAME}` is valid. The `%{}` notation is used for macros, and the engine can expand it, but I'm afraid there is no such macro - feel free to check it. Btw, here is the documentation: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#Macro_Expansion.